# on change from input field how to bring ajax result(values) into html td (cells of table) where i want and needed

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am new to jQuery & Ajax and have a problem which I am not understanding.

In html_purchase page I have:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:5%"><input type="text" name="prdct_cod[]" id="response"   onchange="showUser()"/></td>
<td style="width:8%" class="category-image"><input type="text"  name="pdct_name" readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td style="width:15%" id="tdName"><input type="text"  name="pdct_desc" readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td style="width:8%"><input type="text"  name="pdct_price" readonly="readonly" id="td-name"/></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want that when I enter a value in first input field, the value is passed to getuser.php page through Ajax and after fetching the required result (i.eProdct_name,Prodct_quintity and Prodct_price) from database table, that result is displayed in those input readonly only fields where I want to show them...
My (Ajax) getuser.phpcode is;

```
<?php
      include("include/classess/db.php");
      include("include/classess/user.php");
      include("include/classess/insertion.php");


      $q = intval($_GET['qp']);
mysql_select_db("ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE p_code = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$response = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $response[$i]['p_name']        = $row['p_name'];
  $response[$i]['p_code']        = $row['p_code'];
  $response[$i]['p_description']  = $row['p_description'];
  $response[$i]['p_quantity']       = $row['p_quantity'];
  $response[$i]['price']          = $row['price'];
  $i++;
  }
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and my jQuery code is(which I added in head of html_purchse page):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({
        url: 'getuser.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            data = '';
            $.each(response,function(i,val){
             data = '<td class="category-image">'+val.p_name+'</td>'+
            '<td class="category-link"><a href="#">'+val.p_description+'</a></td>'+
            '<td class="category-desc"><p>'+val.p_quantity+'</p> </td>'+
            '<td class="rating5" >'+val.price+'</td>';
            $('<td>').attr('id',i).html(data).appendTo('#response');
            request.done(function(msg) {
                        $("#response").html(msg);          
                    });

                    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                    });
        })
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should use the `input` event on input fields.
I'd also advise you to go with the loose coupling approach for readability and maintainability. Also means you split DOM/HTML manipulation code from the `XHR` code.

**NB:** If you're getting just 1 Object back from ServerSide then send an Object and not an array. If you however to chose to send an array then in the showData function do
`var response = response[0];` to get the first object in the array, assuming the array has only 1 object in it.

Hope this helps.

```
$('#response').on('input', getData);

function getData(e) {
    var p_code = $(this).val(),
        request = $.ajax({
            url: 'getuser.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'p_code': p_code}, // send the id/p_code as an object and grab it in your PHP script.
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        request
            .done(showData) // pass in the showData callback to handle the HTML manipulation for you
            .fail(errorHandler); // do whatever you like
}
```

Function below handles display the actual data into the fields

```
function showData(response) {
    var $table = $('table');
    $table.find('[name="pdct_name"]').val(response.p_name);
    $table.find('[name="pdct_desc"]').val(response.p_description);
    $table.find('[name="pdct_price"]').val(response.price);
}


function errorHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('jqXHR', jqXHR);
    console.log('textStatus', textStatus);
    console.log('errorThrown', errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir for reply...but it still not working show data function gives an error,and also plz tell what should I write in place of'coke', because that value must come from server side

Comment: Remove the response object from the showData function and then do console.log(response) and tell me what u get

Comment: I added consol.log(response) to showData function in the following maners,but nothing happened[...function showData(response) {consol.log(response)},also with, function showData() {consol.log(response)}...], but I got no output or result..Should I add someting in Ajax page(getUser.php shown above),I thing it because that ajax page not receiving input value(p_code),plz give me   any suggestion.I will be waiting for your help....

Comment: Look at the update I made to the code above. I flagged them **UPDATE**

Comment: Thnks fr your help Mr.dcodesmith... Its all working well now for me jast a little problem plz help me out with it and problem is...it displyes the vaues as 'coke' or 'Charlie Brown, White, Good ish' etc but I want to display here the actual name from databasewhat should i do now plz give me any suggestion...

Comment: Mark it as the answer when you can.

Comment: tnks sir fr ans ...its perfct